# Javascript dropdown onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to make a drop-down that appears when I click an "edit" icon, but I can't seem to make it work.

javascript:

```
function drop() {
  document.getElementById('bsts').style.visibility='hidden';
  document.getElementById('bdrop').style.visibility='visible';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='bsts' style="visibility: visible;">
  <span class='label label-danger'>Permanent</span>
</div>

<div id='bdrop' style="visibility: hidden;">
  <select>
    <option>Temporary</option>
    <option>None</option>
  </select>
</div>

<a href='#' onclick="drop()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
```

Any thoughts on how to make it work?
I have more than 1 div , and when i press edit only the first one works.

Comment: Please format your code before posting it.

Comment: how are you calling the `drop()` method?

Comment: @Praveen yes. with

<a href='#' onclick="drop()">Edit</a>

Comment: Work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/fUTNx/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', '.yourDivClassOrId', function()){
     $('.elementToShowOnClick').slideDown();
}
```

Comment: `jQuery`? which is not tagged. can you tell why you want OP to use?

Comment: it's 2014, if your not using Jquery it's time to step up.

Comment: @HonorableChow, yes, but for simple things like this, there is no sense to load whole library, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    function drop() {
  document.getElementById('bsts').style.visibility='hidden';
  document.getElementById('bdrop').style.visibility='visible';
}
</script>
<div id='bsts' style="visibility: visible;">
  <span class='label label-danger'>Permanent</span>
</div>

<div id='bdrop' style="visibility: hidden;">
  <select>
    <option>Temporary</option>
    <option>None</option>
  </select>
</div>

<a href='#' onclick="drop()">Edit<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
```

Comment: That's exactly what i posted.
my problem is that i have more than 1 div , and when i press edit only the first one works

Comment: @nevermind
The code works, but i use this code inside a table, so i use it more than once, and when i press Edit, only the first one works

Comment: @Joe96, of course, because you use ID, and element id is/should be unique across the page.